# can't find main class java program with two jar files?

Tags: java, linux

This is a pretty basic java question but I'm very new to java. I'm trying to follow this guide:

http://www.egtry.com/java/database/jdbc/hello_teradata

my jar files are located in:

```
tdgssconfig.jar located in /prod/user1/home/tdjar
terajdbc4.jar located in /prod/user1/home/tdjar
```

I created a file called tdTst.java in /prod/user1/home/tdjar dir with the script in the link above.

I than ran

```
java -cp ./:terajdbc4.jar tdTst.java
```

as well as

```
java -classpath terajdbc4.jar:. tdTst.java
```

but keep getting this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class tdTst.java
```

I'm new to java here so what am I doing wrong here? Do I need to point it to both jar files?

Comment: include the code in tdTst.java

Comment: Use `java -classpath terajdbc4.jar:. tdTst` , without the .java

Comment: ok...getting further but how to I include both terajdbc4.jar AND tdgssconfig.jar in that command?

Comment: @ATOzTOA : This is reason for sure why it is not working, It deserves post as regular answer

Comment: So, just checking -- you did compile `tdTst.java` (producing `tdTst.class`) using `javac`, right?

Comment: yeah, I compiled it and still got an error. I found another java program online and compiled that and followed the steps from @ATOzTOA and it worked...seems like the issue was with the program in the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the comment as a separate answer as suggested by @rkosegi

Use java -classpath terajdbc4.jar:. tdTst , without the .java